# Wordpress .htaccess Mobile Redirect (Just Homepage) without affecting Woocommerce AJAX add to cart

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I trying to redirect just homepage to mobile version with this code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera 
mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} wanderingyacht\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://wanderingyacht.com/home-mobile [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It's working fine but AJAX function ADD TO CART for plugin Woocommerce Side Cart  doesn't work at all on mobile devices.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

and REDIRECT is 302